# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL on server 'myhost.com' (101)

Tags: mysql

When trying to connect to my mysql server remotely with:

```
~$ mysql -u user -p -h myhost.com
```

The result is (after asking for password):

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myhost.com' (101)
```

I can connect locally though.

Telnet myhost.com 3306 says:

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable
```

My /etc/mysql/my.cnf is fairly standard (added 0.0.0.0 as a bind address to see if that worked, but alas):

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
#skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
#bind-address       = 127.0.0.1
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
```

Anyone any suggestion where to start?

Comment: Check your firewall.

Comment: I have  '-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT' in iptables, so that should allow remote access to mysql. Anyway, with the firewall blocking access to mysql, how could it ask for my password?

Comment: It's not the server prompting for your password but the the MySQL client. That is not an indicator of connectivity. - Additionally the  `-A` option makes a new firewall rule the last one in a chain, if it is preceded by a reject all rule it will never be reached, a common  misconception.

Comment: I also flushed all my rules with sudo iptables -F, still no luck however.

Comment: It's not a mysql issue (Network is unreachable). Check your hosts file, the routing rules, and check your OUTPUT iptables rules. If the server and the client are on the same server try using the socket "mysql -S /path/mysql.sock

Comment: It is probably a firewall issue indeed (though flushing all rules does not resolve the issue). I will open a new thread under that topic.